# Elementary question on set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Suppose $A \subset B$ then does this imply $B^{c} \subset A^{c}$? Here, $B^{c}$ denotes the complement of $B$. I have tried drawing Venn Diagrams and it seems obvious but is there a formal rigorous proof for it?

Comment: $A \subset B$ is defined as : $x \in A \to x \in B$; then apply [Contraposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).

Comment: oh wow, that is extremely simple! thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does. Suppose $x \in B^c$, we want to show that $x \in A^c$. In other words, we want to show that $x \notin A $. Suppose not. Then $x \in A $. By hypothesis, $A \subset B $, therefore $x \in B $ which is a contradiction since we assumed $x \in B^c $( $x \notin B $). Therefore, $x \in A^c$. We have shown that $B^c \subset A^c $ as desired.